# function definition. invalid index to scalar variable. PYTHON

Tags: python, функции, list

```
def fun(x, k):
    return k[0] * x**5 + k[1] * x**4
```

I want to create a function with a many different coefficients (that code contains only two for example) which I want to pass as a list. Why can't I submit a list? I get an error "invalid index to scalar variable".

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a `list` type variable to the function, then everything should work. The error looks like you are passing a number to the function. To avoid confusion, you can use type hints, like this: `def fun(x: float, k: list):`. Еhen the IDE will indicate a possible error (if you are using an IDE ofk)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык